# How can I add Options to a Select after a specific Option in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a select like this one:

```
<select multiple="" data-live-search="true" class="selectpicker" name="properties[]" id="properties">
        <option class="prop-option" data-parent="10">Test</option>
        <option class="prop-option" data-parent="11" value="1">politico</option>
        <option class="prop-option" data-parent="0" value="2">cantante</option>
        <option class="prop-option" data-parent="0" value="3">show girl</option>
 </select>
```

Now I need to add new options just after the already existing options with data-parent equal to 0.
I tried to work it out using append, before and after but with no luck.

Is there any easy way to append new options just after specific existing options with jQuery?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  // instantiating the main properties
  loadProperties(0);

  $('#properties').on('change', function(){
    var parent_id = $("option:selected", this).val();
    loadProperties(prop_id);
  });

});

function loadProperties(parent_id) {
  var prop_select = $('#properties');
  $.get("json/" + parent_id + ".json",function(options,status){

    if(parent_id === 0) {
      $.each(options, function(val, text) {

        var option = $('<option data-parent="' + parent_id + '" class="prop-option"></option>').val(val).html(text);
        prop_select.append(option);

      });

    }else{

      $.each(options, function(val, text) {
        var option = $('<option data-parent="' + parent_id + '" class="prop-option multilevel"></option>').val(val).html(text);
       // HERE I HAVE TO APPEND THE NEW OPTIONS TO THE RIGHT LOCATION
      });

    }

    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
  });
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try my answer . I am sure it will work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
$.each(options, function(val, text) {
    var option = $('<option data-parent="' + parent_id + '" class="prop-option multilevel"></option>').val(val).html(text);
    // HERE I HAVE TO APPEND THE NEW OPTIONS TO THE RIGHT LOCATION
    $("#properties option").last().after(option);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in `two` ways :-

```
    $.each(options, function(val, text) {
       var option = $("<option data-parent='" + parent_id + "' class='prop-option multilevel'></option>").val(val).html(text);
       $("#properties option:last").after(option);
    });
```

**OR**

```
    $.each(options, function(val, text) {
       $("#properties option:last").after("<option data-parent='" + parent_id + "' class='prop-option multilevel' val='" +val + "'></option>").next().html(text);
    });
```